# Enable Document Set Missing from Site Settings - Site Features

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, modern-experience, custom-content-type

I am a site collection administrator for a team site at my company. I'm trying to enable document sets in a new site, and I can't seem to make it work. I've followed a tutorial to create the document set site content type at the site collection level, but when I try to add it to the library, it's not there.

This is the tutorial I followed: https://sharepointmaven.com/document-sets-hidden-gem-sharepoint/

I get stuck at the "Add from existing content types" step, because "Custom Content Types" isn't in the drop down.

I went to the site collection level to enable "Document Sets" across the site collection, but the option is not listed on the Site Settings > Site Features page.

What is going wrong here?

The site is using Sharepoint Online, and it's using the modern experience.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are looking for the Document Set in the Site Features.  Please note that Document Sets are enabled from the **Site Collection** Features level. There are "Site Features" and "Site Collection Features".